# java - regex within string literal

Tags: java, regex, string, replace

I'm trying to remove something from a string that looks like:

```
"name" : "12345"
```

it will always be that 12345 can be any number, is there a way to do this with something like:

```
string.replace("\"name\":\"[0-9]\",", "")
```

that doesn't work, and i've tried several things but nothing works.

thank you!

Comment: please explain what "doesn't work" mean? What happens and what do you expect to happen?

Comment: Are you assigning the result of `string.replace` to another variable (or back to `string`; or printing it)?

Comment: can you please post what have you tried?

Comment: Use **`replaceAll`**, not `replace`. The former matches regexes; the latter matches the exact string.

Comment: string = string.replaceAll("\"name\":\"[0-9]\",", "")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `+` behind the number part in order for the regex to match numbers of any length. `[0-9]` alone will only match exactly 1 digit.

Furthermore, what about spaces? In your example there are spaces, in your code, there are none. You can add `\\s*` to match any (including none) white-space.

```
string.replaceAll("\"name\"\\s*:\\s*\"[0-9]+\",", "")
```

You can play around with it on [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/ZjyAnq/1).

Andy Turner's comment: You need to use `replaceAll` instead of `replace`. `replace` does not interpret the first parameter as a regex, but tries to find that exact string in your string.

Answer (score 1):

this will do it for you

```
string.replaceAll( "\"name\"\\s*:\\s*\"\\d+\"", "" )
```

example:

```
final String string = "Some\"name\" : \"12345\"String";
System.out.println( string.replaceAll( "\"name\"\\s:\\s\"\\d+\"", "" )
```

will print the output:

> SomeString

And it will work for any number

Answer (score 0):

Replace "\"name\":\"[0-9]\" To  **"\"name\" : \"[0-9]*\""**

Answer (score 0):

I tried a regex like this

```
String regex="\\w+:\\d+";
        String data = "name:12345";
        System.out.println(data.matches(regex));
```

and output is true, you can try around this. \w+ matches one or more word characters and \d+ matches one or more numbers